# How to fix "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" error in RStudio

Tags: r, glm

I am trying to run generalized linear model on my balanced(using SMOTE) train dataset but when I run the below R code I get an error saying

> "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Don't really know what it means. Any help would be highly appreciated!

```
model.glm<- train(Accident_Severity ~ ., data= smote_train, 
                  method = "glm",metric = RMSE, trControl= "ctrl")
```

Comment: What is the structure of `smote_train`?

Comment: It's a data frame containing 1 factor variable(with 2 levels) and 45 numeric variables.

Comment: Sorry - I meant please show us the structure of `smote_train` by showing the output of the `str()` function. A truncated output not showing all the variables is OK, but not preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You have misspecified the options for the `train` function. This may work for you:

```
model.glm <- train(Accident_Severity ~ ., data = smote_train, 
                   method = "glm", metric = "Kappa", trControl= trainControl())
```

In your original function call, the option `trControl = "ctrl"` caused the error message that you got. However, it's also likely that the option `metric = "RMSE"` will not work with your data (I am assuming that your variable `Accident_Severity` is a factor variable and that you are trying to fit a classification model).